# $rootScope is not updated in SPA

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

My first controller:

```
angular.module('application')
.controller('FirstController',['$rootScope',function($rootScope) {  
            var data=[0,1,2];
            $rootScope.items=data;           
   }]);
```

My second controller:

```
angular.module('application')
    .controller('SecondController',['$rootScope',function($rootScope) {                      
                $rootScope.items[0]=3;
                console.log($rootScope.items);  // [3,1,2]               
       }]);
```

When the second controller is running, its corresponding view is changed; however not the same happens when going back to the corresponding view of the first controller (both views are bound to `$rootScope.items`). **Why that happens?** I am using `ui-router` and FirstController has to do with the main page of the SPA and SecondController with another page. Moreover, by keeping track of $rootScope.items with:

```
<pre>
  {{$root.items | json}}
</pre>
```

in both templates the second one is renewed to [3,1,2] and the first one remains [0,1,2].

Comment: You want $rootScope.items[0] to be 0 when you go back to FirstController ?

Comment: Of course not!!

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the problem, may you explain it in details please ??

Answer (score 0):

Passing the same $scope between the two controllers isn't an ideal way of maintaining a single data model, and what you need to do is to establish a service module (or a factory) to manage the data for you, so that both controllers can talk to the factor for your data.

This is how you set up the factory

```
app.factory("Data", 
   function () {
       var storage = [0,1,2]; // where your data is 
       return {
          get: function () {
            return storage; 
          },
          set: function (toSet) {
            storage = toSet;
            return storage;
          }
      };
});
```

to let the controllers know where the data is, use

```
app.controller ("FirstController",
function ($scope, Data)
{
   console.log(Data); // [0,1,2]
   Data.set( [3,1,2]); // demoing change
}
```

same is for the second controller

```
app.controller ("FirstController",
function ($scope, Data)
{
   console.log(Data); // [3,1,2]
}
```